# Rstudio Clean and Rebuild lazy data error

Tags: r, rstudio

I am trying to develop a R package with RStudio. Lately, I have had no success.

```
devtools::build(), devtools::reload() and devtools::check() give:
```

Updating CF documentation
Loading CF
Error in aes(x = gdpPercap, y = lifeExp, size = pop, color = continent,  (from mapping.R#1) : 
                                                                          could not find function "aes" or the data.

```
devtools::check() gives other information, which I list below.

   Clean and Rebuild gives:      
                                                                      1] "/Users/PJO/Desktop/CF_0.1.0.tar.gz"
```

==> R CMD INSTALL --preclean --no-multiarch --with-keep.source CF.2.24

- installing to library ‘/Users/PJO/Library/R/3.4/library’
- installing *source* package ‘CF’ ...
  ** R
  ** data
  *** moving datasets to lazyload DB
  ** inst
  ** preparing package for lazy loading
  Error in aes(x = gdpPercap, y = lifeExp, size = pop, color = continent,  : 
             could not find function "aes"
           Error : unable to load R code in package ‘CF’
           ERROR: lazy loading failed for package ‘CF’
           * removing ‘/Users/PJO/Library/R/3.4/library/CF’
           * restoring previous ‘/Users/PJO/Library/R/3.4/library/CF’

  ```
       Exited with status 1.
  ```

My search has shown that other developers have experienced similar problems. I believe that it connected to (a) devtools and some (b) lingering code. I cannot prove it.

The following efforts have not worked: (1) restarting R, (2) removing invisible files, .R*, (3) rebooting RStudio, (4) debugging all functions with RStudio debug() before committing them to the R package, ... . The error suggests that I have not loaded all the data or required libraries. The above error directs attention to the R library "gapminder." It calls "aes" therefore, it should load. With or without loading "gapminder," I obtain the same error. So, I suspect some hidden files are lurking in the background.

```
To compare, I tested an old version of my CF package. It works:
```

==> R CMD INSTALL --preclean --no-multiarch --with-keep.source CF

- installing to library ‘/Users/PJO/Library/R/3.4/library’
- installing *source* package ‘CF’ ...
  ** R
  ** data
  *** moving datasets to lazyload DB
  ** inst
  ** preparing package for lazy loading
  ** help
  *** installing help indices
  ** building package indices
  ** testing if installed package can be loaded
- DONE (CF)

Other attempts include using browser() and traceback() from Rstudio debug() fail. They fail because of the Clean and Rebuild fails before debug() is called.

```
Some devtools::check() failures for my latest CF package:
```

The Title field should be in title case, current version then in title case:
  ‘Stochastic traffic performance and car-following modeling tools’
‘Stochastic Traffic Performance and Car-Following Modeling Tools’

── Install failure ─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────

- checking for empty or unneeded directories
  Removed empty directory ‘CF/inst/extdata’
  Removed empty directory ‘CF/inst’

  - looking to see if a ‘data/datalist’ file should be added
  - building ‘CF_0.1.0.tar.gz’

  Some devtools::check() failures for my older CF package:

  The Title field should be in title case, current version then in title case:
  ‘A package for performing analyses with stochastic traffic performance and car-following models’
  ‘A Package for Performing Analyses with Stochastic Traffic Performance and Car-Following Models’

plotfollow2: no visible binding for global variable ‘leff’
  Undefined global functions or variables:
    leff

These errors do not cause Clean and Rebuild error.

```
As you can see, I have run out of things to try. For another, I am experienced enough to know if I am overlooking something. For example, I am taking the Title problem seriously. To be honest, the suggested corrective action does not make sense to me.
```

Help would be greatly appreciated.

Paul

Comment: I discovered that Clean and Rebuild fails because Error in aes(x = gdpPercap, y = lifeExp, size = pop, color = continent,  : 
  could not find function "aes".
Error : unable to load R code in package ‘CF’

Comment: I discovered that Clean and Rebuild fails because; Error in aes(x = gdpPercap, y = lifeExp, size = pop, color = continent,  : 
  could not find function "aes"
Error : unable to load R code in package ‘CF’  "aes" is a deprecated package.

Comment: Obviously, the `package:aes` is not part of my search() list. My revised question is how to use to direct my package from attempting to load a **deprecated package,**  which does not exist? The **function** `aes`is part of the `gapminder` package. It is loaded but it does not stop my package to load `package:aes.`